# How to use `where` to filter a non attribute value in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my `member` `model` I have a method like this to calculate a value :

```
def currentreg
 if self.currentaward
  self.send(self.currentaward.downcase).regdate
 end
end
```

The database is like this :

```
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  awardunit_id    :integer
#  name            :string(255)
#  address         :string(255)
#  district        :string(255)
#  gender          :string(255)
#  dob             :date
#  contact         :string(255)
#  email           :string(255)
#  operator        :string(255)
#  entrylvl        :string(255)
#  guardianname    :string(255)
#  guardianaddress :string(255)
#  guardiancontact :string(255)
#  guardianemail   :string(255)
#  currentaward    :string(255)
```

I want to know how to filter the `currentreg` using `where` method?

Comment: it's a computed value, not stored in the database, ActiveRecord is used to query the database. You can filter your dataset using ruby array methods but it will not be as efficient.

Comment: @EApubs AFAIK we cannot get method value usig active record query method instead you can use any rails callbacks to call that method in your model

Comment: you cannot filter currentreg using where as it is not a value in the database... you can, however, filter to some extent off of current award (the value currentreg appears to be calculated from)... I would not recommend trying to filter by the value that is contained inside of currentaward, but you could potentially filter by the presence of a value using where... you'd still have to do a select if you want to filter by the actual value of currentreg but with fewer records, the select should be a little quicker... still might not be worth the effort though